# "Test in Web Chat" not working now, but was working fine 2 days back

Tags: c#, azure-bot-service

I created a bot using Azure Bot Services, modified the code, did continuous deployment and then tested it ("test in web chat"). It was working fine 2 days back, but is not working now. Now, even if I create a new web bot (the ones provided by Azure: c#, v4 SDK, basic-bot) and test it, it doesn't work. I have no clue about what I did wrong.

If anyone could help.

Comment: Hello, "This does not work" is not helpful to let others help you. please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can actually help.

Comment: ok,sorry for that.I followed steps from (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to make a basic bot.But the step which says "test  the bot" doesn't work the way it is showed on the page. I mean i get nothing like "conversationUpdate event detected".All i get is a tab to enter message,but nothing happens when i enter a message and send it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it,the issue was  with the network and not with anything else.Everything is working fine now.Sorry for bothering.